# Problem fetching blob from Azure Storage: Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-storage, credentials, blobstorage

I am building a **Spring Boot Application** to upload and retrieve **BLOB data** (images or documents) from the **Azure Storage**. For the purpose I followed the documentation given here-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-storage

I am using VSCode IDE for building and running the project. When I try to retrieve the data using-
http://localhost:8080/blob/readBlobFile,
I get the following error-

```
[Request processing failed: com.azure.identity.CredentialUnavailableException: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
Managed Identity authentication is not available.
SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.
IntelliJ Authentication not available. Please log in with Azure Tools for IntelliJ plugin in the IDE.
AzureCliCredential authentication unavailable. Azure CLI not installed.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/azclicredential/troubleshoot
Azure PowerShell authentication failed using defaultpowershell(pwsh) with following error: Unable to execute PowerShell. Please make sure that it is installed in your system.
Azure PowerShell authentication failed using powershell-core(powershell) with following error: Az.Account module with version >= 2.2.0 is not installed. It needs to be installed to use Azure PowerShell Credential.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azure-identity-java-default-azure-credential-troubleshoot] with root cause

com.azure.identity.CredentialUnavailableException: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
Managed Identity authentication is not available.
SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.
IntelliJ Authentication not available. Please log in with Azure Tools for IntelliJ plugin in the IDE.
AzureCliCredential authentication unavailable. Azure CLI not installed.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/azclicredential/troubleshoot
Azure PowerShell authentication failed using defaultpowershell(pwsh) with following error: Unable to execute PowerShell. Please make sure that it is installed in your system.
Azure PowerShell authentication failed using powershell-core(powershell) with following error: Az.Account module with version >= 2.2.0 is not installed. It needs to be installed to use Azure PowerShell Credential.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azure-identity-java-default-azure-credential-troubleshoot
```

I am not able to find the reason for this problem. Can somebody help me find the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Here I have a work around where Instead of using the `application.yaml`  to connect to azure blob storage we can manually configure and fetch the file.
- To do this we would need a connection string (available in portal under keys tab), blob name, container name and endpoint.
- Then we create a blob service client, a blob container client and a blob client in the exact order as above.

```
@RestController  
@RequestMapping("blob")  
public class BlobController {  
    private String enpoint = "https://<Storage Account Name>.blob.core.windows.net/";  
 private String connectionString = "";  
 private String containerName = "test" ;   
 private String blobName = "document.txt" ;  
  
  @GetMapping("/readBlobFile")  
    public String readBlobFile () throws IOException  
    {  
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient =  new BlobServiceClientBuilder()  
                .endpoint(enpoint)  
                .connectionString(connectionString)  
                .buildClient();  
  BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);  
  BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);  
  ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
  blobClient.downloadStream(outputStream);  
  
 return outputStream.toString() ;  
  }  
}
```

- Here it would return anything in the blob as a string
  [image]
- Now regarding the error, you are facing, as the error message state try installing the azure cli if running locally

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Azure uses [Default Azure Credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/identity-azure-hosted-auth#default-azure-credential) when you developing locally in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-storage), it will attempt to authenticate via the following mechanisms:

[image]

Below authentications failed based on error message:

- Managed Identity authentication (This will take effect when you deploy to Azure hosting service, like [Azure Spring Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/products/spring-apps/#overview))
- SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication
- IntelliJ authentication
- AzureCliCredential authentication
- Azure PowerShell authentication

Please be sure you did these 2 things to fix the problem.

1. Make sure the Azure AD account you used have the right account access.

> Important: In your newly created Azure Storage account, assign the Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the Azure account you're currently using. For more information, see [Assign Azure roles using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal).

2. Ensure one of the authentications listed previously take effect. For example, [Sign in with Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli) could make `AzureCliCredential` take effect.